# SmoothBivariateSpline User Warning error in python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am using SmoothBivariateSpline interpolation for a 2-D unstructured dataset in python.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

L = np.loadtxt('Somefile.txt')

P = L[:,0]  # extracting first coloumn (independent variable 1)
H = L[:,1]  # extracting second coloumn (independent variable 2)
T = L[:,2]  # extracting third coloumn (dependent variable)

Spline = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(P, H, T, kx=3, ky=3, s=0)
```

i am getting the following error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\fitpack2.py:639: UserWarning: ier=2348
warnings.warn(message)
```

Can sombody tell me what might have gone wrong??

Thanks